# Elastic search java api 1.3 aggreagation - bucket size always zero

Tags: java, elasticsearch, size, aggregation, bucket

I am trying to use elastic search java client here. I tried running this following piece of code using shakespeare example data

```
final Client client = new TransportClient()
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));

final SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("shakespeare")
    .setTypes("line")
    .setSource("{\n" +
            "  \"size\": 5,\n" +
            "  \"aggs\": {\n" +
            "    \"group_by_state\": {\n" +
            "      \"terms\": {\n" +
            "        \"field\": \"state\"\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      \"aggs\": {\n" +
            "        \"average_balance\": {\n" +
            "          \"avg\": {\n" +
            "            \"field\": \"balance\"\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}");

searchRequestBuilder.
    execute(new ActionListener<SearchResponse>() {
        public void onResponse(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
            final Terms terms = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("group_by_state");
            System.out.println(terms.getBuckets().size());
            client.close();
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            client.close();
        }
    });
```

The result I get is

```
    !!skipped initial part!! 
    }, {
      "_index" : "shakespeare",
      "_type" : "line",
      "_id" : "92972",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"line_id":92973,"play_name":"The Tempest","speech_number":4,"line_number":"3.3.17","speaker":"SEBASTIAN","text_entry":"Will we take throughly."}
    } ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_state" : {
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

But If i run the same query in command line using

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "size": 5,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_state": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "state"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_balance": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "balance"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And the result -

```
"aggregations" : {
"group_by_state" : {
  "buckets" : [ {
    "key" : "al",
    "doc_count" : 21,
    "average_balance" : {
      "value" : 25377.571428571428
    }
  }, {
    "key" : "tx",
    "doc_count" : 17,
    "average_balance" : {
!!SKIPPING!!
```

I am not sure what the problem is.. I have also tried looking at the test cases [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/1.x/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/bucket/ShardSizeTermsTests.java) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is wrong index you are looking at (using java api),

Your java api is like

```
final SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch("shakespeare")
    .setTypes("line")
    .setSource("{\n" +
```

and curl request is like

curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -d '

So, search in **shakespeare** in java api and **bank** in curl, and  ??

Or, Everything is ok!!

Comment: That was a complete blunder from my side for asking such a dumb question without re checking the code. Thx a lot.